# displaying all records from one table and matching records from another

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a tables below that has records of activites and points

```
Activites
|A_ID   |Site        | ActivityValue| ActivityName
 ---------------------------------------------------
|1      | site1      | 7             | ActivityName1
|2      | site1      | 6             | ActivityName2
|2      | site1      | 6             | ActivityName3
|2      | site1      | 6             | ActivityName4  



pointsTable
|UserID |RemainderPoints  | Active         | ActivityName |
------------------------------------------------------
|1      | 10              | TRUE           | ActivityName1| 
|2      | 5               | TRUE           | ActivityName2| 
|2      | 5               | TRUE           | ActivityName3| 
|2      | 5               | TRUE           | ActivityName3|
```

what I need is return all records from Activities

```
SELECT  ActivityName FROM activity WHERE `Site`='Site1'
```

Returns

```
ActivityName1
ActivityName2
ActivityName3
ActivityName4
```

Then I need to sum user points based on user id  from pointstable

```
SELECT UserID, ActivityName, Active,  SUM( RemainderPoints) 
FROM pointstable
WHERE UserID =2
AND Active =  'TRUE'  GROUP BY ActivityName
```

Returns

```
|UserID |RemainderPoints   | Active         | ActivityName |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2      | 5                | TRUE           | ActivityName2| 
|2      | 10               | TRUE           | ActivityName3|
```

All that's fine separately but I need them put together for the user i.e

```
ActivityName1  = 0
ActivityName2  = 5
ActivityName3  =10
ActivityName4  = 0
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Yes. See JOIN. It's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an outer join:

```
select 
    a.activityName, 
    coalesce(sum(pt.remainderPoints), 0) points
from 
    activities a left outer join pointsTable pt on 
        pt.activityName = a.activityName and pt.UserID = 2
group by a.activityName
```

or a subquery:

```
select
    activities.ActivityName,
    coalesce(
        (select sum(RemainderPoints) from pointsTable where pointsTable.UserId = 2 and pointsTable.ActivityName = activities.ActivityName)
    , 0) points
from
    activities
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first query, did exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT a.ActivityName,SUM( p.RemainderPoints) 
FROM activity a left join pointstable p on a.ActivityName =p.ActivityName 
WHERE p.UserID =2 AND p.Active =  'TRUE' and a.site ='Site1' 
GROUP BY  a.ActivityName`

Hope this helps!